# How to access an element of a set element?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set like [("something1",12),("something2",43)]. How do I access the string?

I can access elements of the set but can't access elements of set element.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
i=0
size=0
tup=set()
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage'):
    for cl in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\plant_tomato_leaf_dataset\plantvillage\\'+file):
        i+=1
    print(i)
    tup.add((file,i))
    i=0
    size+=1
#print(tup)
x = set()
for i in tup:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

I want to print only strings after checking if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of the set is a tuple.  You can access the first item in the tuple with [0] like this:

```
x = set()
for item in tup:
    print(item[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> ss =  {("something1",12),("something2",43)}
>>> ss
{('something2', 43), ('something1', 12)}
>>> [s[0] for s in ss]
['something2', 'something1']
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `s[0] for s in ss`?

Comment: Correct! Sorry :)